# <img src="#"> Means in HTML?

Tags: html

I do have the following code in my HTML:

```
<img src="#" alt="image alternative text" />
```

What does `src="#"` mean? Because in HTML, I cannot have empty `src` attribute for an image tag. And if we do not have that attribute, visual studio 2012 will throw a suggestion.

Thanks

Comment: Looks like a placeholder that some script may use for responsive/lazy loading.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you don't want any image to be loaded using src attribute (probably load the image dynamically later), you need to set src empty. But when you do that, browsers still send calls to server.

Browser behavior for empty src (Source: http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html)

> Internet Explorer makes a request to the directory in which the page
>   is located. Safari and Chrome make a request to the actual page
>   itself. Firefox 3 and earlier versions behave the same as Safari and
>   Chrome, but version 3.5 addressed this issue[bug 444931] and no longer
>   sends a request. Opera does not do anything when an empty image src is
>   encountered.

To avoid the unnecessary call to server, instead of using empty src, `src="#"` could be used which forms a hash url and hash urls are not sent to server.

Let's say base url is : http://mysite.com/myapp/

`src=""` -> Absolute url: http://mysite.com/myapp/

`src="#"` -> Absolute url: http://mysite.com/myapp/**#**

Comment: Good reasons why one should not use `src=""` (or omit the `src` tag) for the Image element, especially since such has been made *invalid* in HTML5. (I'm not sure how HTML4 defines it.)

Comment: I don't know why, but my experiments show this to be the opposite of what actually happens - ie if I set src to '', then I get no network request, but if I set src to '#', then I do get a network request. Try it in chrome dev tools and see - open the network panel then in console type: `var myImg = new Image(); myImg.src = '#'` -> network request...`myImg.src = ''` -> no network request.

Answer (score 1):

As with the `href` attribute of an anchor element, `<img src="#">` is roughly equivalent to `<img src="thecurrenturl#" ..`> (but see the fiddle example for why it's not identical).

As it is written `src` will never refer to a valid image resource but, presumably, something/someone can change the URL later or otherwise manipulate the element. Since the `src` attribute [is required](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/embedded-content-1.html#the-img-element)<sup>1</sup>, substituting in such a valid "dummy" value appeases tools like the Visual Studio editor.

[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zwEds/1/) shows the behavior which can be observed by using the DOM `src` property.

---

<sup>1</sup> "The src attribute must be present, and must contain a valid non-empty URL .."

Answer (score 1):

Most people use it as a placeholder for links just so that there are no errors when the code compiles. If a programmer gave you some code with the "#" as a placeholder, they probably want you to interchange it with a web URL.

Answer (score 0):

More than likely just a placeholder subject to change dynamically based off of an event listener (or like @FabricioMatte suggested, a lazy loading technique.) It could also be just a placeholder to bypass any potential errors.

Answer (score 0):

In `src="#"`, the attribute value is a reference to the start of the document at the current base URL, according to the URL standard, STD 66 aka [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986). You would need rather special arrangements to make that actually work as a reference to an image.

*Why* anyone would use such an attribute is a different question, and a yet another question is what is the problem that the construct is supposed to address.

Comment: *"what is the problem that the construct is supposed to address"* --> Dynamically setting the url with js but maintaining correct HTML that passes W3C validation.