# Regarding img src

Tags: html, image

I 'd like to understand how the following piece of code works

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
 <title>Title</Title>
</head>

<body>
<form  method="POST" action="/link" >   
    <div id="form1" >
        <input type="file" class = "btn btn-danger">
        <img id="pic" src="#" alt="HTML5 Icon" > 
    </div>          
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class = "btn btn-info">
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

I am trying to render images when using a file upload handler and apparently at this point the code breaks. It seems to have the effect of reloading the page again and again.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense: you say "I 'd like to understand how the following piece of code works" and then "the code breaks" … so it **doesn't** work. That code doesn't make any sense, you're claiming the image src is the top of the current HTML document … since that is an HTML document and not an image, how could it work?

Comment: I an using a file handler to upload images. There are multiple post requests made to the server. I have disabled all other lines of codes and even the javascript function. Currently this is what I have on the HTML page

Comment: https://validator.w3.org/nu/

Comment: Thanks for the link. I did validate the HTML. Here is what happens. If I use a link in the src attribute, say "/file/someimage.jpg", there is a single post request. However when I use the src="#" attribute multiple post request happens. I 'd like to understand why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

The question is similar to one already asked in stackoverflow.

[[<img src="#"> Means in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19613841/img-src-means-in-html][1])

I think that the "#" attribute was calling the url again and set up a sort of infinte loop that was resulting in the multiple post requests to the server.

Anyways, got the code to work by using a default image filename instead of the "#"